# React Redux TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

Hi I'm using redux persist to persist and rehydrate my app. This is my productsReducer:

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
  id: [],
  qty: [],
  numOfItems: 0,
  totalPrice: 0,
  status: '',
  showPopup: false
};

const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  let updatedId = [...state.id];
  let updatedQty = [...state.qty];
  let index = updatedId.indexOf(action.id);

  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.status
      }

    case actionTypes.FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.status,
        products: action.products
      }

    case actionTypes.TOGGLE_POPUP:
      return {
        ...state,
        showPopup: !state.showPopup
      }
    };
    .....
}
```

For reasons unknown to me, my persist/REHYDRATE actions show one key {showPopup: true} for productsReducer.

```
action     
{type: "persist/REHYDRATE", payload: {…}, err: undefined, key: "root", asyncDispatch: ƒ}
  asyncDispatch: ƒ asyncDispatch(asyncAction)
  err: undefined
  key: "root"
  payload:
  productsReducer: {showPopup: true}
  userReducer: ...
  _persist: {version: -1, rehydrated: true}
  __proto__: Object
  type: "persist/REHYDRATE"
```

After that FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST, show productsReducer: {showPopup: true} too. This shows that the rehydration replaced productsReducer state in the beginning.

```
action FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST
  prev state 
    {productsReducer: {…}, userReducer: {…}, _persist: {…}}
    productsReducer: {showPopup: true}
```

When the fetched products calls productsReducer, it tried to do `let updatedId = [...state.id]`. But that didn't work since productsReducer only have the state showPopup. That's when it threw the below error...

> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.

I suspect the fault lies in persist/REHYDRATE. How can I reset the app or reset rehydration then?

Comment: can you show the remaining parts of `productsReducer`. also would help to just `console.log` state or state.id on your line 14

Comment: Have you tried doing this  `let { id, qty } = state` and then `let updatedId = [...id]`.

Comment: @delis added the remaining parts of productsReducer. console.log() state or state.id on line 14 doesn't work too... The app throws this error before any console.log() occurs.

Comment: @AmolBJamkar tried it, throws the same error too

Comment: @helplah, I mean the `productsReducer` itself...include the rest of it. May give a bit more context.
For now, try: `let updatedId = Array.isArray(state.id) ? [...state.id] : [];` but still `console.log` your `state` (before the assignments)

Comment: @delis console.log state shows `productsReducer.js:14 {showPopup: true}`

Comment: @helplah it appears somewhere along the line, your state is being emptied (I suspect when `action.type` of `persist/REHYDRATE` is fired). You have a default case yes? (that likely returns just the state.

Comment: @delis yes you're right! I'm afraid the problem lies with redux persist/rehydrate. I am going over to their github issues to find answers.

Comment: clear your local storage for `localhost:3000`. In chrome, click the padlock icon(or whatever there is) which is on left side of the url bar. From there you can remove cookies and local storage. Usually I keep a action called `PURGE` in all reducers, which I fire on logout. It sets the state to initial state(default object you use for state in parameters of the reducer)